# canvas, canvas-arc, javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Can't diminish canvas arc's value with input (it accepts larger than default values but not the smaller ones), what to do?

```
var button = document.querySelector(".btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var input = document.querySelector(".inp").value;
        var c = document.querySelector(".canvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, `${input}`);
        ctx.stroke();
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

The canvas should be cleared before you draw the next arc, if not they will overlap.

Just add `ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);` before the arc.

See sample below

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".btn");
var c = document.querySelector(".canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
  
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var input = document.querySelector(".inp").value;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, `${input}`);
  ctx.stroke();
})
```

```html
<button class="btn">click me</button>
<input class="inp" value=3.14><br>
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```